# Does the class of all functions between 2 proper classes exist in Ackermann set theory?

Tags: set-theory

[Ackermann set theory($AST$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory)
(like $NBG$ and $MK$) admits both sets and classes but
differs from $NBG$ and $MK$ in that a proper class can be an element of another proper class.

It is easy to [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249807/the-class-of-all-functions-between-classes-nbg)
, the class of all functions between 2 proper classes does not exist in $NBG$ or $MK$ (more precisely, it is the empty class).

But what about Ackermann set theory?
Does the (nonempty) class of all functions between 2 proper classes exist in Ackermann set theory?